# does emberjs have an equivalent to rails `yield :something`?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, templates, ember.js

In rails you can do things like:

application.html.erb:

```
<h1><%= yield :title %></h1>
<%= yield %>
```

someother_template.html.erb:

```
content_for :title { 'Some Title' }

other stuffz
```

Is there a way to do this sort of thing using emberjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this sort of thing using emberjs?

If you want yield-as-in-layouts then yes, you can use the handlebars `{{yield}}` helper to wrap a view

```
AViewWithLayout = Ember.View.extend({
  layout: Ember.Handlebars.compile("<div class='my-decorative-class'>{{yield}}</div>")
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("I got wrapped"),
});
```

See [Ember.Handlebars.helpers#yield](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_yield)

If instead you want yield-as-in-content-for, there is not a direct parallel AFAIK. Not sure the content-for pattern really makes sense in the context of handlebars templates, since content_for is about making an assignment from within a template. The preferred way in ember to set something like {{title}} in your application template is binding it to a property of the application controller.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had a feeling there was no direct equivalent. I'm currently doing it the way you suggested by setting values in the application template.